# How can I write __weak UIView* v = view; on Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
__weak UIView * v = view;
[self moveView: v];
```

How can I write in swift?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part of that Obj-C code do you find problematic to translate to Swift?

Comment: I am absolutely newbie in developing. I trying to become a developer. Please dont toxic for me and just help. Of course I try to solve problems by myself. But in earlier way newbies has a stupid questions. It's normal. Thank you

Comment: @AliCoder Did you tried this ```weak var v: UIView? = UIView()
    weak var mmoveView:UIView? self.mmoveView = v```

Comment: weak var v = UIView?()
self.moveView(view: v)

Comment: @EkramulHoque yes. Thank you for help. But It's doesn't help to solve it

Comment: Setting `v` to a new instance of `UIView` is not the same as the OP's code, which uses an existing variable, `view`, which must have been defined previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
__weak UIView * v = view;  //Create weak var v that points to `view`
[self moveView: v];        //Call moveView using the new weak var
```

in Swift would be

```
weak var v: UIView? = view  //Create weak var v that points to `view`
self.moveView(v)           //Call moveView using the new weak var
```

or you might want to rename the function moveView to `move(view:)` to be more "Swifty"

### Edit:

Note that based on a comment you made, it looks like your `moveView(_:)` function takes a non-optional variable. In that case, just get rid of the weak variable and pass in view directly:

```
self.moveView(view)           //Call moveView using view directly
```

Comment: shouldn't `weak` variable be an optional?

Comment: Indeed it should. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: weak var v: UIView? = view------self.moveView(view: v!)-----

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you very much! Now my project works all right! But Sulthan told really nice thing that there must be optional. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Wait, something is wrong. The syntax you posted, `self.moveView(view: v!)` is "force-unwrapping` the optional var `v`. That is usually a bad idea. If moveView wants a non-optional variable then you might want to get rid of the weak variable and just pass view directly.